# Django-Taggit | Getting ALL tags, but only related to blog

Tags: python, django, tags, django-taggit

I am using `django-taggit` to tag three different types of models:

- a blog
- a list of events
- a list of products.

This all works fine.

I am now trying to grab a list of **all** the available tags **related** to the blog so I can display them on the BlogIndex page. The furthest I've gotten is, thanks to a similar SO question:

```
from taggit.models import Tag

def blog_tags(self):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return tags
```

However this gives me a list of every single tag, including the product and event tags.

How do I filter that list of tags down to just the blog?

**EDIT** | `modely.py` simplified:

```
class BlogPostTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('BlogPost', related_name='tagged_items')

class BlogPost(Page):
    # my fields
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPostTag, blank=True)

    # Getting BlogPost-specific tags here is not difficult

class BlogIndex(Page):
    # my fields

    def blog_tags(self):
        etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for an answer to this question, I found a simple workaround:

```
def blog_tags(self):
    tags = BlogPost.tags.most_common()
    return tags
```

This lists all the tags associated with the `BlogPost` model in order of most used to least used.

Answer (score 0):

If tags are directly put on your `Blog` object (that I'll call here `myBlog`) and you want to fetch all of them, here's what you can do :

```
myBlog.tags.all()
```

However, this might not be what you're looking for : please do post the code related to your models.

**EDIT.**

What I gather from the code is that you tag your blog posts with a custom class `BlogPostTag` that inherits `TaggedItemBase`, an abstract class that looks like [this](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/models.py) :

```
class TaggedItemBase(ItemBase):
      tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, 
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I can't test it because there's not enough code, but I think you might be able to fetch all the tags on your blog posts by doing something like this :

```
  BlogPostTag.objects.all().values('tag')
```

Keep us posted! Thank you :-)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your comment. I'll edit my post to include some models, but my tags are associated to a `BlogPost` model, not the `BlogIndex`